# readAsDataURL not returning image type

Tags: javascript, filereader

How can we enforce to return image type(if in case it is not returning) while using readAsDataURL to read the image,

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#file").on("change", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            existingNode = document.getElementById("addMore");
            var files = event.target.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.onload = function(event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var formElement = document.getElementById("submitForm");
                var dataToBeSent = new FormData(formElement);

                count++;
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = '<div class="fl pu_mr1 pu_mr2 wrap' + count + '">' + '<div class="photobox posrel">' + '<div class="posabs txtc fontlig color2 f14 lh30 pum35 dispnone retryMessage"><i class="up_sprite pu_retry pu_mt2"></i>Retry</div>' + "<img class='classimg1 opa50 uploading" + count + "' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>" + '<div class="posabs pu_pos1" onclick="deleteThisPhoto(' + count + ')"><a href="#" class="up_sprite pu_cross"></a></div>' + '<div class="posabs fullwid pu_pos2 uploadingBar' + count + '">' + '<div class="wid80p brdr12">' + '<div class="bg7 hgt10 mrl0 uploadingPercent' + count + '" style="width:0px;"></div>' + '</div></div></div></div>';
                output.insertBefore(div, existingNode);
                generatingDiv.innerHTML = "";
                formDataArray[count] = dataToBeSent;

            };
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);   //Read the image
        }
```

Comment: If possible , can post `js` ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `File` object has `type` property which contains the mime type:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  var fileType = file.type;
  console.log(fileType); // image/png
}
```

The `FileReader` object returns a base64 string which has the mime type as well, which you can extract with this function:

```
function base64MimeType(encoded) {
  if (!encoded) return;
  var mime = encoded.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/);

  if (mime && mime.length) return mime[1];
}

var picReader = new FileReader();
picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
var base64 = picReader.result;
console.log(base64MimeType(base54)); // image/png
```

**JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mr2g5dx1/2/**

Here's a little module I created: https://github.com/miguelmota/base64mime

Comment: tested on sony xperia L version 4.1 , still image type is null while alerting :(

Comment: @user1850796 what do you get when you do             `alert(JSON.stringify(file))` ?

Comment: It returns file array with details name,size,LastModifiedDate and type.
but type is empty(type="").
on Android(4.2) native browser

Comment: Weird. And the base64 string doesn't have a mime type either? `alert(picReader.result)`

Comment: image type is missing in "alert(picReader.result)".